# Update for .NET Framework 4 (KB2468871) not installing as prerequisite component

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, clickonce, publish, prerequisites

I publish a ClickOnce application with one prerequisite component: "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64) and Update for .NET Framework 4 (KB2468871)", using VS2013.

When I run setup.exe on Windows XP the installer installs only Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile without the required update.

Is there any way to force installing the update during setup? Without the update my application doesn't work properly, and I'd like to avoid having to install the update manually.

I've seen a similar problem solved here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/bcc7e3fb-6462-4dae-8d84-e81a6ec79809/clickonce-install-latest-updatespatches-for-net-framework-prerequisite?forum=winformssetup but if in VS2013 we have specific option to choose "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64) and Update for .NET Framework 4 (KB2468871)" prerequisite to install then I wonder why it doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

Regards,
Maciek Jakubczyk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've republished the app and this time "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64) and Update for .NET Framework 4 (KB2468871)" prerequisite did what it was suppose to do. I have no clue why, but for now it solves my problem.